# How to get list of ads using a custom(saved) audience on facebook

Tags: facebook-ads-api

So far, I have tried to list the ads for each audience from this endpoint:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/marketing-api/reference/custom-audience/ads/

in combination with the list of custom audiences I got from   `/AD_ACCOUNT_ID/customaudiences`

The list of audiences looks alright but I am getting an empty array for the `/CUSTOM_AUDIENCE_ID/ads` endpoint (this is an active account so the audiences are clearly in use)

Answer (score 1):

Ads data is in fields.

Please try this url

{custom audience id}?fields=name,ads{adset_id,account_id}

Comment: I have tried that and I don't get any fields for ads.

Comment: look like i missed the first part.<customaudience id>?fields=name,ads{adset_id,account_id}  Are you getting the audience id with the url {act_<adaccount id>}/customaudiences

Comment: Yes, I know which endpoint you are referring to. I just dont have the ads field available.

Comment: Please check if custom audience is associated with the ad account. You can check with url {act_<adaccount id>}/customaudiences

Comment: The audience ids come from `act_<id>/customaudiences`. It's actually part of the script flow...